# pyTelegramBotAPI нужно чтоб в группе отвечал на определенные сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Добавил бота в группу, в личных сообщениях все прекрасно работает, а вот в группе ни на что кроме commands не отвечает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```py
@mybot.message_handler()
def answers(message):
    if message.text == 'Как дела?':
        mybot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нормально', parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отключите Group Privacy в [BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Закрывайте вопрос нажав на галочку слева от ответа